# Partial Derivative of $xy^{\sin z}$ in direction to z?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I tried to solve this problem using Chain Rule.
$$
f(x,y, z) = xy^{\sin z}
$$
Solve $f_z$.

I tried:

Derivate the outside (derivative of a constant is 1) with power $\sin z$ multiplying by $cos z$.

But I think it's wrong. How to solve when the outside is a constant?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you know logarithmic differentiation?  It works for partial derivatives also.

Comment: How could you solve $f_z$, if you do not write for which value it needs to be solved.

Comment: Where can I study about this? Why ln?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If $x>0$ taking logarithms we get $$\ln f(x,y,z)=\ln x+\sin z \ln y.$$ So

$$\dfrac{\partial \ln f}{\partial z}=\cos z\ln y.$$

Can you finish?

(If $x<0$ just consider $-f=-xy^{\sin z}.)$

Comment: Hmm, I tried $$f_z = x \cdot \frac{d}{dz}y^{\sin z} = x\cdot \ln(y)\cos(z)y^{\sin z}$$ But that doesn't seem to be the same as yours. Is it hiddenly the same thing, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Alec  No, they're the same.

Comment: You seem to have the wrong $f(x,y,z).$ Also you can't apply $\ln$ if $x<0.$

Comment: Where Can I study about this? I can't get it.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation

Comment: $\log(f(x,y,z)) = \log(x) +\log(y)\sin(z)$, you did your logs wrong.

Comment: @james.nixon Thank you very much for noticing it. Typo fixed. At the first sight I have considered $f=(xy)^{\sin z}.$ Then I have modified the solution without having in mind what you correctly say.

Comment: @zhw You're right. I have misread the function. If $x<0$ we can proceed in the same way just considering $-f.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in \mathbb R$ and $y>0$ are constants, then the derivative of $xy^{\sin z}$ with respect to $z$ is $x(y^{\sin z}\cdot \ln y\cdot \cos z).$ That by definition is $f_z(x,y,z).$

If this seems confusing, try letting $x= 3,y=5$ for example. You then want to compute the derivative of $3\cdot 5^{\sin z}$ with respect to $z.$ You're back in one variable calculus and you get the answer $3\cdot 5^{\sin z}\cdot \ln 5\cdot \cos z.$

Comment: Where Can I study about this? I can't get it. thanks guy Why ln?

Comment: @ComplexityAlg Do you know how to differentiate $5^x?$

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/exponential-functions-differentiation-calc/v/chain-rule-for-derivative-of-2-x

Comment: @ComplexityAlg It's absolutely standard and in any beginning calculus course or text.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the chain rule. Let $t=\sin{z}$. Then:
$$f_z=(xy^t)_z=x(y^t)_z=x(y^t)_t \cdot (t)_z = x(y^t\ln{y}) \cdot (\sin{z})_z=x(y^{\sin{z}}\ln{y})\cdot \cos{z}.$$

Comment: Why ln? I can't understand! :( I can't get it. thanks guy

Comment: There is the formula: $(a^x)'=a^x\ln{a}, a>0$. E.g. $(2^x)'=2^x\ln{2}.$